# Change variable value of the already running program

Tags: c++, variables, winapi, runtime

I think it is impossible, but I should try.

I have a program, that is doing a physical simulation and recording frames to files. It is recording until the breakup value is not achieved, like:

```
int counter=0; //global variable

void SomeFunction()
{
...
if(counter == 400) //written exactly by this way, i.e. 400 is not a variable, just a number
PostQuitMessage(0);
else
MakeScreenshot();

counter++;
...
}
```

The problem is that I forgot to change `if(counter == 400)` to `if(counter == 1000)` and now program will be finished with 400 frames, although I need exactly 1000.

I can’t just recompile the program because calculations are very heavy and the program is already running for 2 days, I can’t wait.

It is very important for me, is there any way to change the `if` statement, or exactly the variable value during the program running?

---

The only hope I have, is, as far as I remember there was programs that could like change money/health/another stuff in games, and there user exactly could search a variable by value, and change it

Currently it is on about 200-300 frame, I have so little time to fix it.

Comment: It may be possible in debug builds.

Comment: @Ayxan, unfortunately it is release

Comment: Using a debugger you should be able to break in and modify the upper bound of the loop. Easy in a debug build, less easy but not impossible in a release build.

Comment: @JonathanPotter how can I do that? Just use “join the process”(don’t know how it will be correctly in English) from Visual Studio, and then change code and press ctrl s?

Comment: Yes, attach to the process, break in, find the loop and the change the 400 to something else and let the process continue. Unless the optimiser has unrolled the loop, but it's unlikely to have with 400 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows functions [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) and [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory).

But you need to determine the position of the value `400`. Looking for the value in the running program can be done with the above functions. Depending on the size of the constant, it should be either a `USHORT` or an `UINT`.

So you can use the following steps:

1. Look for the value in a second instance
2. Isolate the surrounding OpCode sequence.
   For example, a `cmp xxx, 400`
3. Look for this OpCode sequence in the running executable to find the unique location and replace the crucial value by `1000`.

This can be called "hot-patch". It's how simple in-memory cheats do work and requires root privileges.

Comment: But 400 is not stored in my code as a variable, but literally as number. After compilation it becomes a variable?

Comment: No. It's a constant. But this constant is necessarily represented in the corresponding assembly code. And therefore, you can find it (and replace it). The part with the OpCode sequence is merely required to find **the right** 400 value (out of several possible occurences).

Comment: Can You, please, explain steps in more details? What do You mean by “second instance”. What does the second step mean literally?

Comment: This just means executing a second instance for testing. You do not want to crash the running program, do you? So try it on a second instance, first.

Comment: And I actually didn’t get the main idea of how to find address where the 400 value is stored.

Comment: Of course, you could do all this manually, yet it's a *lot* more involved than you make it appear. You would also have to use debug information to find the memory location with confidence. Or simply use a debugger, and be done in less than a minute.

Comment: Do I need to read by a chunks and check whether there is “400” or not? From what point should start to search? Like 0x000000?

Comment: @IInspectable it would be perfect if someone give more details

Comment: You have all the details. If you do not know how to use a debugger, then now is the time to learn.

Comment: @IInspectable, and actually, computer, where the program is running doesn’t have neither Visual Studio, not a source code

Comment: So, install WinDbg, and point it to your symbol store. Maybe ask someone that understands assembly language, debugging, and programming in general for help.

Comment: It should be literally cmp xxx,400? May 400 be written as hex?

Comment: 400 is a *value*. `400` is how we *display* that value in decimal. You are looking for **opcodes**, not the literal string `cmp xxx, immediate`. Chances are there isn't even a `cmp`. More like just a `dec`, followed by a conditional jump (`jz` or `jnz`). If that has you stumbling, stop doing whatever you were trying to do. You **will** break things. Post your code at Code Review, and have someone optimize it, to help you regain your lost time.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Cheat engine](https://www.cheatengine.org/) and found address of the counter variable by its value. Through all addresses, the address I need was colored in green.

I changed the value stored at that address to 401, and now all is ok.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @IInspectable on each iteration it calculates math, gets numerical solution for system of particles, draws updated scene, makes screenshot and save it as a file with name $counter_variable_value.jpg. So after changing it via that program I saw, that it skipped file “40.jpg” and made “41.jpg” . Apologize for incorrect code at the beginning